# MSACCESS - How to customize all the Switchboard entries texts at once by a condition

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a default Switchboard generated by MS Access and i want to customize every single entry of the list at once.

The Switchboard form by default is set on "contiunous form" and the entry's control is a textbox (`ItemText`) identified via VBA as `OptionLabel1`.

I added to the default "Switchboard Items" table a new field called "`SecLevel`" where i added for each entry/record a value like `Admin`, `Operator` and `User`.

Now i want each item in the Switchboard form's list to change its text color based on "`SecLevel`" value like red for Admins and blue for Operators.

So i tried like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value = [ItemNumber].Value

Dim ctrl As control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

If ctrl.Name = "OptionLabel1" Then

    If DLookup("[SecLevel]", "Switchboard Items", TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value) = "Admin" Then
        
        Me.OptionLabel1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    
    ElseIf DLookup("[SecLevel]", "Switchboard Items", TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value) = "Operator" Then
        Me.OptionLabel1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    
    Else
    
        Me.OptionLabel1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

This doesn't work help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrong `Dlookup` criteria. You want to fetch the `SecLevel` of the `Switchboard Item` with same `Item Number` as stored in `TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value`. use:

   ```vb
   DLookup("[SecLevel]", "Switchboard Items", "[Item Number] =  TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value")
   ```

   or `TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value` gets converted to True (if <> 0, first values is fetched as criteria is true for all rows) ot False (if = 0, no values is fetched)
2. Wrong event.`Form_Current` event is fired every-time you move the forms recordset cursor to another record. To execute code on form startup, use `Form_Open` if you don't need values from bound queries/fields (e.g. to check priviligdes and close if not sufficent priv) as it fires before data is fetched.
   But as you need `[ItemNumber].Value`use `Form_Load` event (fires when form with data is loaded.
3. On a continuous Form  a control inside Details-Section is copied for every record, but still has same name. In `Form_Current` event `Me.OptionLabel1` always refers to the control in actual selcted row. All other copies are not affected.
   To work around use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/highlight-data-with-conditional-formatting-7f7c0bd4-7c37-421d-adad-a260125c8129) or use `Detail_Paint` event.

Some other improvements can be:

- if you know controls name, no need to loop whole Controls collection, just refer to by using `Me.Controls("NameOfControl")`.
- use [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) to tell different values of an expression apart. E.g.

  ```vb
  Select Case DLookup("[SecLevel]", "Switchboard Items", "[Item Number] = " & TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value) 
      Case "Admin" '
          ' code on Admin here
      Case "Operator"
          ' code on Operator here
      Case Else
          ' code executed if no match in cases
  End Select
  ```

  Be aware of case-insensitive string comparison if usual [Option Compare Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-compare-statement) is set.
- Use proper naming conventions! Even you don't seem to tend to ugly ungarian-notation `OptionLabel1` is a poor identifier, not telling us anything useful. See [variable names](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/3832/variable-names) for some good infos (also check the rest of the site as it contains lots of good advices!). In table/field names avoid special chars, only use letters, numbers and underscore, then you don't need square brackets! Also get used to rename controls dropped from a query/table, as otherwise the control and the data field get the same name what can cause some trouble! Another great resource on vba coding is [RubberduckVBA](https://rubberduckvba.com/) addin (try it:)) and their blog. Even they focus a lot on Excel, there is no better resource to learn OOP vba coding. Maybe start with [bad habbits](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/clean-vba-code-pt-1-bad-habits/) and then move on where you like (I recommend [OOP Battleship Part 1: The Patterns](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/08/28/oop-battleship-part-1-the-patterns/))

Comment: i added to the Switchboard form another textbox linked to SecLevel field so i can retrive the SecLevel value of each ItemText row than i use the conditional formatting way to compare the new txtSecLevel.Value with a String value such as "Admin" or "Operator", simple enough! thanks

Comment: check your "Contional Formating" text link has some errors

Comment: Note that you can avoid string concatenation in a `DLookUp`: `Lookup("[SecLevel]", "Switchboard Items", "[Item Number] = TempVars!CurrentItemNumber.Value")`. Then, we're parameterizing using a tempvar which DLookUp supports.

Comment: @ErikA Good catch ;) Always feel free to add those minor misses to my answers without notifing, as I criticize that if other don't use params. AT Alex: parameterizing criterias prevents injections, see [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com)